# Como usar o realloc() dinamicamente na alocação de struct?

Tags: c, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados

Tenho uma estrutura  `struct TMedidorEletrico *medidor;`, e é preciso realocar a memoria para esta estrutura de forma dinâmica, até o momento em que o usuário encerre o *loop*. ***A memoria deve ser realocada um passo de cada vez***, porem quando invoca a funcao `realloc()` pela segunda vez ocasiona o seguinte erro:

*** Error in `./Ex14CompaniaEletrica': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000001c46010 *
Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)***

Codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio_ext.h>

int criaEstrutura(void);

struct TMedidorEletrico
{
    int numero_consumidor; //Numero do consumidor.
    float kWh_mensal; //Quantidade de kWh consumido ao mes.

    int tipo;
    /* 1 – residencial, preço em reais por kWh = 0,3
       2 – comercial, preço em reais por kWh = 0,5
       3 – industrial, preço em reais por kWh = 0,7
    */
    float custo_total;
};

struct TMedidorEletrico *medidor;

int main(void)
{
    criaEstrutura();

    float total_consumo_geral = 0.0,
          qtd_tipo1,
          qtd_tipo2;
    int qtdLeitura = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nInforme o numero do %d consumidor: ", qtdLeitura + 1);
        scanf("%d", &medidor[qtdLeitura].numero_consumidor); //Se o usuario digitar 0 encerra o loop while.
        __fpurge(stdin);

        printf("\nInforme o consumo do kWh total no mes: ");
        scanf("%f", &medidor[qtdLeitura].kWh_mensal);
        __fpurge(stdin);

        printf("\nInforme o tipo, 1-Residencial 2-Comercial 3-industrial: ");
        scanf("%d", &medidor[qtdLeitura].tipo);
        __fpurge(stdin);

        if(medidor[qtdLeitura].numero_consumidor == 0) //Condição que encerra o loop.
            break;
        else
            if(medidor != NULL) //Testa caso == a NUULL siguinifica que na a mais espaco na memoria para realocar.
            {
                qtdLeitura++;

                /*Quando passa aqui pela primeira vez ocorre tudo certo, porem na segunda vez da erro.*/
                medidor = (struct TMedidorEletrico *) realloc(medidor, sizeof(struct TMedidorEletrico) * 1);
            }
            else
                break;
    }

    return 0;
}


int criaEstrutura(void)
{
    medidor = (struct TMedidorEletrico *) (malloc(sizeof(struct TMedidorEletrico) * 1)); //Aloca a primeira vez

    return 0;
}
```

Gostaria que o programa continua-se armazenando os valores no struct para futuramente serem tratados.
Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O programa está realocando mas mantendo o mesmo tamanho:

```
sizeof(struct TMedidorEletrico) * 1
```

O realloc() não "soma" o tamanho que é passado como segundo parâmetro. Esse será o tamanho total novo. Para atingir o resultado esperado, que é abrir espaço para mais elementos, o realloc deveria usar o tamanho

```
sizeof(struct TMedidorEletrico) * (qtdLeitura + 1)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, irei implementar aqui, e voltarei para postar o resultado.

Comment: Fiz a alteração, porem o erro persiste.

Comment: Tinha ainda um erro off-by-one na minha resposta, já editei acima. Assim como no primeiro malloc(), o realloc() tem de somar 1 em qtdLeitura. Testei o código inclusive com Valgrind e funcionou. Aliás, fica a dica de usar o Valgrind num próximo problema destes (não sei se você está desenvolvendo no Linux.)

Comment: Fui o teste aqui e funcionou. Muito obrigado pela ajuda...
Outra duvida, eu nunca ouvi sobre o Valgrind o que ele seria?
Eu estou desenvolvendo no linux (Ubuntu 14.04), a IDE e o codeblocks com GCC.

Comment: O Valgrid é um programa de depuração que testa cada acesso a memória, então se há tentativa de acesso fora do tamanho de uma área, como estava aconteceno no seu caso, ele avisa na hora onde aconteceu, bem antes do programa quebrar.

Comment: Obrigado, vou instalar ele aqui e começar a usar.

Comment: Poderia me dizer quais comandos deve especificar para o valgrind?

Comment: Nenhum, basta chamar valgrind ./binário